# How to bundle MahApps.Metro into single exe

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro, smartassembly

I'm having a really hard time bundling all of my dependencies in my C# WPF project into a single exe, using SmartAssembly 6 (evaluation/trial), because of MahApps.Metro.

This conclusion was drawn when creating a completely empty project with nothing but MahApps.Metro, and still not being able to bundle it.

It throws an exception with an inner exception `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I've spent a day and a half trying to resolve this, Googling the error, trying every suggestion I can find, and posting in the official MahApps.Metro chat (https://gitter.im/MahApps/MahApps.Metro). I've tried all kinds of variation where I removed System.Windows.Interactivity dll, added it, moved it to another path, etc.

Using the latest MahApps.Metro package from NuGet, and .NET 4.5. The program works when I run it from Visual Studio 2012, or when I run the application from Debug/Release.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before? How did you resolve it? Is the problem the bundle application (SmartAssembly 6) or MahApps.Metro? Are there any other bundle programs that you know, or think, will work with MahApps.Metro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is my way to put the dlls in a single exe

1) create a folder named `DllsAsResource` and put the `MahApps.Metro.dll` and `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` with `Add as Link` to it

2) change the `Build Action` for the dlls to `Embedded Resource`

3) change `Copy Local` to `false` for the normal referenced dlls

4) create Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo
{
  public class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {
        var resourceName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".DllsAsResource." + new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) {
          if (stream != null) {
            var assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
          }
        }
        return null;
      };

      App.Main();
    }
  }
}
```

5) set the `Startup object` to the `Program.cs` in your project properties

6) now you have a single exe without publishing the hole dlls

you can look at this [demo](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo.git) for all the tips

hope that helps

Comment: thanks for answering this! After a few days of trying to bundle it without any success I gave up, but I will definitely give this a try and mark this as answer if/when it works :)

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply (haven't had the time to implement this). But this works great! Thanks alot! :)

Comment: Have you check to see if application's load time doesn't suffer too much?