# Bundling MahApps.Metro DLL causes System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, bundle, mahapps.metro

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725420/how-to-bundle-mahapps-metro-into-single-exem) you can embed `MahApps.Metro.dll` and `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` into your project and bundle them into 1 exe. 
Unfortunately this will cause an exception on `App.Main();` in mentioned Program.cs.

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional Information: Line number "8" and position "18" System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source

I looked up the [demo-project](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo.git) only to find the exact same project-setup that i already had.
Tried to catch the InnerException:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File or assembly "MahApps.Metro, Culture=neutral" not found

```
Dateiname: 'MahApps.Metro, Culture=neutral'
bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
bei System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
bei System.Windows.Navigation.BaseUriHelper.GetLoadedAssembly(String assemblyName, String assemblyVersion, String assemblyKey)
bei MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer.GetResourceManagerWrapper(Uri uri, String& partName, Boolean& isContentFile)
bei MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer.GetPartCore(Uri uri)
bei System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPart(Uri partUri)
bei System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
bei System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
bei MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetContentType(WebResponse response)
bei MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponseStream(WebRequest request, ContentType& contentType)
bei System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.set_Source(Uri value)
bei MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
```

Just to make clear, i copied the 2 dlls form the demo project and pasted them into an additional extern "lib" folder, then added them to the intern `DllsAsResource` folder as link and referenced them in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the problem myself.
It seems like the `Assembly Name` and `Default Namespace` (Project menu->Properties) must be **exactly** the same. Mine was different, Assembly Name contained '!' which was replaced in Default Namespace with '_' thus creating this error.

You can rename your Application after compiling.