# Issue with bundling DLLs in MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo sample project

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

Here is the sample project I'm using on GitHub: [MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo)

Here is the original question I found on StackOverflow: [How to bundle MahApps.Metro into single exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725420/how-to-bundle-mahapps-metro-into-single-exe/22119351#22119351?newreg=c61ebcc0d57548d88fc2a4f02837c48b)

My goal is to be able to run the compiled EXE file on another computer without including the *MahApps.Metro.dll* and *System.Windows.Interactivity.dll* files alongside the executable.

I am using the VisualStudio Professional 2013 IDE and have not modified the demo project aside from installing the MahApps.Metro NuGet package.

Here are the exact steps I'm currently attempting:

1. Run the debugger and make a copy of the compiled executable from the "project name"\bin\degbug directory.
2. Place the copy of the compiled executable file on another computer and attempt to run it.

The application fails to run and the *System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException* error gets recorded in the Windows Application log.

However, when I copy the previously mentioned DLLs and place them within the same directory alongside the executable file it runs successfully.

Am I not compiling the project correctly to get the desired result?

I've verified all of the items posted by punker76, in the response to the previously linked question, and everything matches.

Comment: mh, downloaded my example, compiled it, and it works for me...

Comment: Thank you for the response punker76; when you compile do you still see the dll files in your bin\debug directory? The references are set to "Build Action: Embedded Resource" and "Copy to Output: Do not copy", yet they show up in the debug directory when the project gets compiled. P.s. How did you add the references to the dll's as a link in your demo project?